# How to keep ampersand in a different font?

Tags: fonts, font-encodings, ampersand

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[math]{iwona} %nice font
\renewcommand{\mathsterling}{\textrm{\textsterling}}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\section{EAL \& SEN}
A \& B

\end{document}
```

Bookmarks works fine. But not in the document. How can I keep the `ampersand` in the same format as in the bookmark?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: The font used to display the bookmarks is controlled by the PDF viewer, not anything to do with LaTeX. So it is nearly impossible to guarantee the ampersand in the document looks the same as it does in the bookmarks.

Comment: @PaulGessler I really hope there is a way to keep the ampersand as I have used this font for many articles, and I want to keep it consistent. Never thought about this problem before and it looks like a nice font!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Document

The font `iwona` does not contain an alternative for the ampersand. Therefore, a different font is needed for this symbol, when the more common form is preferred. The following example uses the ampersand from the CM Bright fonts (also package `cm-super` should be installed). Two alternatives are in the comments.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[math]{iwona} %nice font
\renewcommand{\mathsterling}{\textrm{\textsterling}}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\&}{%
  \nfss@text{%
    %\fontfamily{lmss}%
    %\fontfamily{LinuxBiolinumT-TLF}%
    \fontfamily{cmbr}%
    \selectfont
    \symbol{`\&}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\section{EAL \& SEN}
A \& B
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Bookmarks

The font in the bookmarks cannot be changed, because the bookmarks in the PDF file are simple text strings without font information (except that bold or italic could be specified for a whole bookmark title string). The fonts are chosen by the PDF viewer, see the [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303097/how-to-keep-ampersand-in-a-different-font#comment734699_303097) of Paul Gessler.

Comment: This works, although not in section titles (on my end). Is there a way to circumvent this problem? (using \fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont \itshape in a document typesetted in Libertine).

Comment: @Mogu Since the example of the answer uses a section title that works, make a new question with a full, but minimal example that shows the problem.

Comment: Hi, I did just that : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/601443/cmr-italic-ampersand-in-libertine-environment

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{librecaslon}
\begin{document}
{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont{\itshape\&}\par}{\itshape\&}
\end{document}
```

Extracted from the link: https://texblog.org/2014/06/17/typographic-ligatures-or-the-history-of-ampersand/