# CMR italic ampersand in Libertine environment

Tags: fonts, libertine, ampersand

I tried to use the code provided in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303097/how-to-keep-ampersand-in-a-different-font/310695?noredirect=1#comment1508268_310695) to use the Computer Modern italics' ampersand in a document typesetted in Libertine. However this only works in the "body" of the text but not in section titles.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}    
\usepackage{libertine}
 

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\&}{%
  \nfss@text{%
    \fontfamily{cmr}%
    \selectfont
    \itshape
    \symbol{ `\&}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
 \section{Image \& Direct Image} 
 Image \& Direct Image
\end{document}
```

[image]

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `libertine` package sets `\bfdefault` to `b` and indeed you get the warning

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/b/it' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/b/n' instead on input line 16.
```

but you can help and define your own font substitution rule.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{libertine}

% provide the necessary substitution rule
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmr}{b}{it}{<->ssub*cmr/bx/it}{}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\&}{%
  \nfss@text{%
    \fontfamily{cmr}\itshape
    \symbol{`\&}%
  }%
}
\makeatother % <- don't forget

\begin{document}
 \section{Image \& Direct Image}
 Image \& Direct Image
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I don't know whether or not it'd useful to say this, but I'm not getting the warning with the previous code (I'm compiling with pdflatex).

Comment: @Mogu Not all front-ends show every warning. Check in the log file